# using statement in conjunction with Repeater DataBinds and events

Tags: c#, linq, eval, idisposable, using

In relation to the below code, does the using statement take into consideration objects called via _ItemDataBound methods and Eval methods when finding objects that need disposing of?  Or will it try to dispose before attached events and evals are fired since they occur later in the life cycle?

In other words, does it only dispose the datacontext after all the Evals and attached Events to the repeater are called or will this cause datacontext has already been disposed errors?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (EventManager manager = new EventManager())
    {
        EventDates = manager.GetWhatsOn(Request.QueryString["category"]);

        rptEventDates.DataSource = EventDates;
        rptEventDates.DataBind();
    }
```

...

```
public class EventManager : IDisposable
{
    private MainDataContext db;
    public EventManager()
    {
        db = new MainDataContext();
    }

    ....other methods....

    public void Dispose()
    {
        db.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In relation to the below code, does the using statement take into consideration objects called via _ItemDataBound methods and Eval methods when finding objects that need disposing of?

No. It doesn't "find" objects to dispose at all - it just disposes of the object referred to in the first part of the statement. So your code is broadly equivalent to:

```
EventManager manager = new EventManager();
try
{
    EventDates = manager.GetWhatsOn(Request.QueryString["category"]);

    rptEventDates.DataSource = EventDates;
    rptEventDates.DataBind();
}
finally
{
    manager.Dispose();
}
```

Nothing else will be disposed, but the `EventManager` itself definitely *will* be disposed.

If anything requires the resource *not* to be disposed of until later, you shouldn't use a `using` statement.

Comment: Thanks Jon, makes sense.  So really that code is fine, but I shouldn't be wrapping the repeater with a using statement, instead let garbage collection do it's job?

Comment: @A-Bop: I don't know what `EventManager` is or what the `GetWhatsOn` method does, so it's hard to say whether your code is okay or not.

Comment: That's fair enough, I'll try to explain what I'm getting at - sorry if it's not very clear.  If EventDates contains objects that are called on Eval() on the repeater, but the object originated from the datacontext inside the EventManager - is the datacontext disposed of at Eval because it's in a using statement?

Comment: @A-Bop: If you just force eager evaluation, e.g. calling `ToList()`, then you should be okay to dispose of the data context. I don't think `Eval` is going to dispose of anything - you'd just end up with a data context which isn't disposed of. I don't know which LINQ provider you're using, but for LINQ to SQL that's generally not a problem.